# How can I keep my just bought dozen of popsicles cold as long as possible?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, ice, cold-atoms

It's hot and I bought a dozen of pear popsicles. I discovered the fridge with freezer is dead. How can I keep them cold as long as possible so I don't have to eat them all at once?

Answer (score 2):

Pack them in a thermos flask, where the vacuum between the walls prevents easy heat conduction from the inside to the outside. Then put it in a working fridge. Then launch the fridge into space (behind a reflective solar shade) on a trajectory where it gets a gravity assist into interstellar space. If you do this really right you may even get a launch into intergalactic space in the very long run. Then they will remain cool until proton decay.

The key issue here (beside the fun of solving physics problems) is that a good question has a somewhat well-defined set of plausible or valid solution methods. Especially when it is an "engineering" issue where we try to achieve an outcome rather than ask what happens if a system is allowed to evolve according to standard physical law, we end up with a vast set of possible solutions: the question is under-constrained in a very serious way.

Comment: I was going to suggest liquid helium, but this is more epic.

Answer (score 0):

If they are plastic wrapped then blow a fan across them to help cool your house. Later dump them into Tupperware Popsicle makers and refreeze them.